# Would graphite foam soaked in helium float?

Tags: material-science

I was watching this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bIXUBXj070&feature=youtu.be

and they say that the material is 1/6'th the density of air. In the comments, particularly this one: "That's a lie it is NOT1/6 the density of air... If it were it would float away﻿" by a user named Cello Man, we've been discussing that. I linked them to this:

[If aerographite is lighter than air, why doesn't it float?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71069/if-aerographite-is-lighter-than-air-why-doesnt-it-float)

related question, but the user Muzik bike asks "If I were to soak it in helium, would it float?﻿" I've scrounged around the internet looking to see if anyone has tried that, and came up blank.

I think it would float at least until the helium escaped, which would be really really cool! So has anyone tried it? And what do you think, would it float?

Comment: How does one soak something in a gas?

Comment: @KyleKanos how about; glue the sponge to the bottom of a beaker, invert that, take a canister of helium, discharge some of the helium such that it floats up into the beaker...

Comment: Rather than glue it could just be some low force clamps that can easily be released and wouldn't damage the sponge.